# Trace identity for $2 \times 2$ reflections

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, traces

Let $A, B, C \in \mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ be reflections (i.e., their eigenvalues are $\pm 1$). Please show that

$$ \DeclareMathOperator\Tr{Tr}\{\Tr(AB)\}^2+\{\Tr(BC)\}^2 + \{\Tr(CA)\}^2 - \{\Tr(AB)\}\{\Tr(BC)\}\{\Tr(CA)\}\\ = 2 + \Tr\left((ABC)^2\right) $$

holds.

Comment: Why would you like us to show this?

Comment: We can transform this identity into a few similar identities using the identity $\text{tr}((A_1\dots A_r)^2)-(\text{tr}(A_1\dots A_r))^2=2\cdot(-1)^r$ that holds whenever $A_1,\dots,A_r\in\text{GL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ are reflections.

Comment: @JosephVanName, do you have a reference for [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439405/trace-identity-for-2-times-2-reflections#comment1133704_439405) identity?

Comment: @LSpice The identity follows from the observation that if $X$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix with eigenvalues $\mu,\lambda$, then $2\det(X)=2\mu\lambda=(\mu+\lambda)^2-(\mu^2+\lambda^2)=\text{tr}(X)^2-\text{tr}(X^2)$.

Comment: The identity in the question holds even if we do not assume that $A,B,C$ are self-adjoint but only have eigenvalues 1,-1.

Comment: Do you have a response to the answers on this page?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple proof that can be done without Mathematica (and without trigonometry).

A general $2\times2$ reflection matrix is of the form
$$M(a,t):=\begin{bmatrix}a&t\\(1-a^2)/t&-a\end{bmatrix}$$
with some complex $a,t$ (or the limit, $\pm\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\z&-1\end{bmatrix}$ for any $z\in\mathbb C$, of $M(\pm\sqrt{1-tz},t)$ as $0\ne t\to0$). This follows because a reflection matrix has trace $0$ and determinant $-1$.

By diagonalization, without loss of generality (wlog)
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$$
and, by continuity, we can also write
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}b&u\\(1-b^2)/u&-b\end{bmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad 
C=\begin{bmatrix}c&v\\(1-c^2)/v&-c\end{bmatrix}$$
with some complex $b,u,c,v$.

Substituting these expressions for $A,B,C$ in the identity in question and simplifying, we verify the identity.

---

This argument should work for $2\times2$ reflection matrices $A,B,C$ over any field -- except that, instead of the limit transition, one would have to consider separately the cases when at least one of the matrices $B,C$ is lower triangular; but those cases should be even easier to check than the "main" case, when $B$ and $C$ are not lower triangular.

Comment: I always appreciate your Mathematica-based answers, but, unfortunately, images are not the most useful way to sling around precision-text-based information.  A while ago I edited one of your Mathematica posts to text, but you reverted that edit.  Is there any searchable, cut-and-pastable interchange format you would be comfortable with using in place of images of Mathematica?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker : That opinion about `FindInstance` is incorrect, according to Mathematica documentation. Go to https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html, click there on "Details and Options", and you will see this: "FindInstance[expr,{x1,x2,…}] **gives results** in the same form as Solve: {{x1->val1,x2->val2,…}} **if an instance exists**, and **{} if it does not** [emphasis mine]."

Comment: Previous comment continued: My own experience with `FindInstance` also does not agree with that opinion: Oftentimes, `FindInstance` may keep going for hours or days if it cannot find a required instance and cannot prove that such an instance does not exist -- whereas numerical commands such as `NMinimize` finish in a fraction of a second.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker : That is a specially programmed exception, with the null result accompanied by this message: "FindInstance::rhyp: Warning: FindInstance assumed the Riemann hypothesis in order to prove the solution set found is complete."

Comment: @CarloBeenakker : In fact, I think this exception, for `FindInstance[Zeta[s] == 0 && Re[s] != 1/2 && Im[s] != 0, s]`, only reinforces the point that the output of `FindInstance` is rigorous -- even though Mathematica can and does make mistakes (but arguably not so much as an average professional mathematician).

Comment: @LSpice : Thank you for your comment. I try to make my answers as readable as possible. Text-based versions of Mathematica notebooks are hardly readable. However, I have now provided a link to the Mathematica notebook itself, even though I suspect few would be willing to use it.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker : In view of this discussion, would you also like to reconsider your first, "only means" comment?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker : Why? Do you see any basis whatsoever for that opinion?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439405/trace-identity-for-2-times-2-reflections/439512?noredirect=1#comment1133683_439512), thank you!  I agree that probably no-one is going to run the notebook for this specific example, but it makes it a lot easier to study your Mathematica code and adapt and modify it for future examples.

Comment: @LSpice : Thank you for your comments. I will try to keep this in mind.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker : In your first comment here, you referred to an opinion, which you later said was also your **opinion**. **You have not provided any basis** for that opinion. In fact, the **Mathematica official documentation is contrary to that opinion**, as noted in my first response to your first comment. Yet, in your initial comment you presented that opinion, with no apparent basis in fact and contrary to existing evidence, as **fact**. Therefore, I suggest you delete that "only means" comment while you are further researching this issue.

Answer (score 4):

$\DeclareMathOperator\Tr{Tr}$For real matrices $A$, $B$, $C$ the proof can be done "by hand": parameterize an orthogonal reflection matrix as
$$M_n=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta_n&\sin\theta_n\\
\sin\theta_n&-\cos\theta_n\end{pmatrix},$$
with $A=M_1$, $B=M_2$, $C=M_3$. Note that $(M_1M_2M_3)^2=I$. Then one has
$$\Tr M_iM_j=2\cos(\theta_i-\theta_j),
\quad\Tr((M_1M_2M_3)^2)=2,$$
and the left-hand-side and right-hand-side of the equation in the OP both evaluate to 4, in view of the identity
$$\cos ^2(\theta_1-\theta_2)+\cos ^2(\theta_2-\theta_3)+\cos ^2(\theta_3-\theta_1)=1+2 \cos (\theta_1-\theta_2) \cos (\theta_2-\theta_3) \cos (\theta_3-\theta_1).$$

---

For complex matrices the parameterization is
$$M_n=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta_n&e^{i\phi_n}\sin\theta_n\\
e^{-i\phi_n}\sin\theta_n&-\cos\theta_n\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then one has
$$\Tr M_iM_j=2\cos\theta_i\cos\theta_j+2\cos(\phi_i-\phi_j)\sin\theta_i\sin\theta_j.$$
The trace of $(M_1M_2M_3)^2$ is a lengthy expression, which according to Mathematica is equivalent to
$$\Tr(M_1M_2M_3)^2=[\Tr M_1M_2]^2+[\Tr M_3M_1]^2+[\Tr M_2M_3]^2-[\Tr M_1M_2] [\Tr M_3M_1] [\Tr M_2M_3]-2.$$

Comment: I couldn't get Mathematica to simplify $\operatorname{Tr}(M_1 M_2 M_3)^2$ on its own, but it did consent to verify your identity:  `With[{M = Function[{theta, phi}, {{Cos[theta], Exp[I phi]Sin[theta]}, {Exp[-I phi]Sin[theta], -Cos[theta]}}]}, With[{M1 = M[theta1, phi1], M2 = M[theta2, phi2], M3 = M[theta3, phi3]}, Simplify[Tr[MatrixPower[M1.M2.M3, 2]] == Tr[M1.M2]^2 + Tr[M3.M1]^2 + Tr[M2.M3]^2 - Tr[M1.M2]Tr[M3.M1]Tr[M2.M3] - 2]]]` returns `True`.

Comment: @LSpice --- indeed, the trigonometric identies are cumbersome, I was not able to do it by hand, but Mathematica's "Simplify" works.